# How can I tell if my IContainerGroup.ExecuteCommandAsync() code method ran?

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I am trying to connect to a container instance and run a command on it using

```
IContainerGroup.ExecuteCommandAsync("dockerImage", "Command","Command".Length, 1);
```

This returns a password and a webhookUri. What am I supposed to do with that information?

It doesn't appear that my "Command" worked. I have tried something as simple as

```
"/bin/sh -c \"touch fileTest.txt\""
```

but that doesn't work.

I am at a loss.

Comment: seems to me you're missing the authentication part: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/containerinstance?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: I'm able to get the containergroups after logging in via service principal. I receive a response from the ExecuteCommandAsync I'm just not sure if it's of any value.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? I didn't see any updates

Comment: What is difficult that you don't accept the answer and also do not give any response. It's won't take you too much to accept it as the answer!

Comment: It didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions in your description. One is how to do with the WebSocket the code returned. Another is the command that executes in the ACI doesn't work.

A1: You need to access the WebSocket URI and send the password, then it will return the result of the command which you execute in the ACI via the C# code. You can take a look at WebSocket in C# [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.0#send-and-receive-messages).

A2: To execute commands in the ACI, it does not support arguments, so you just can execute the single command such as `ls` and `pwd`. ACI is quick to start and good to run the application, but it's not good to interact.

For the second question, if you want more controls and interactions with your application, the AKS is better than ACI.